# Are there any decent compiler web services?

Tags: web-services, compiler-construction, build-automation, web-farm

Here's the idea: you commit your code to a repository and call a web service (or enter the request through a web app) to have it compiled.  The results are then pushed up to a FTP server, S3 bucket, etc.  Is there anything like this out there on the public internet?

TFS has a build queuing feature, but I'm thinking more along the lines of a *internet* (not intranet) web service.  And if it can pull from known source control interfaces (Subversion, CVS, etc.) then the caller needs to pass very little besides selecting a compiler and specific compilation options.

My reasoning is more along the lines of removing a lot of software installation and configuration hassles, especially when working between different languages/platforms/frameworks/projects

Comment: that's a great idea, because compiling a code base is way too fast these days - more time for coffee!

Comment: My reasoning is more along the lines of removing a lot of software installation and configuration hassles, especially when working between different languages/platforms/frameworks/projects.

Comment: you might want to add that to your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there build farm for checking open source apps against different OS'es?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160793/is-there-build-farm-for-checking-open-source-apps-against-different-oses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is there build farm for checking open source apps against different OS'es?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160793/is-there-build-farm-for-checking-open-source-apps-against-different-oses) for related information.

Comment: Excellent ... looks like I'm not the only one asking, just asking in a different way.